# Creating dynamic URL's with PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, vanity

)

I am creating a dynamic event creation application and I have run into a problem when creating dynamic webpages for events.

My .htaccess looks like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f  
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} >""
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ table.php?event=$1 [L]
```

And my table.php looks like

```
$getEvent = explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
print_r($getEvent);
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}   
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM event where link='$getEvent[4]'");
echo $getEvent[4];
```

The page structure is as following :

```
http://page.ex/~name.name/reg/
```

And when I try to entry

```
http://page.ex/~name.name/reg/joulupidu
```

I get 404 although "joulupidu" is in event table. I have no idea where to look, because I haven't done much work with this kind of stuff before.

Thanks, 
WK!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .htaccess should be like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/reg/([^/.]+)?$ reg/table.php?event=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

And your table.php file shoul be like

```
$getEvent = $_REQUEST['event'];
//print_r($getEvent);
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}   
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM event where link='$getEvent'");
echo $getEvent;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input. It nows seems to point to the right URL but it still says 404 when I'm trying to go to my GetEvent url

Comment: Let's say I have a link="test" in my event table, so when I go to http://page.ex/~name.name/reg/test , it says 404

Comment: Still 404, manually typing reg/table.php?event=test works, so it must be htaccess

Comment: Check the htaccess again, and if not working than give me the path where your table.php file

Comment: I try to access the above link but manually typing the link also throws 404

Comment: replace name.name with werner.koppel, sorry

Comment: did you add the htaccess code that I edit 2nd time above?

Comment: I can't even manually access the url either. But If you wish, can directly solve this issue on your server. Find me on facebook

Comment: I added you to facebook